# Getting the date format for grep -E in Unix

Tags: unix, datetime, grep

I write the dates on my file with the next format

```
date +%a-%b-%d-%Y
```

My goal in my exercise is to get the list of the dates in my file.
I know I need to do it with `grep -E`, but I don't know how to put correctly the format of the date.

Desired input:

```
"grep -E (the format of the dates I'm looking for)" ~/file1
```

Desired output:

```
Tue-Oct-15-2013
Wen-Oct-16-2013
Wen-Oct-16-2013
Thu-Oct-17-2013
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean. Can you show some input and desired output?

Comment: I edited the topic. Hope its clearer now..

Comment: But what does `file1` contain?

Comment: Just text that contains dates with the format I explained about

Answer (score 6):

Try following:

```
grep -E '[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{4}' ~/file1
```

Or more concise

```
grep -E '\w{3}-\w{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}' ~/file1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be explicit about it and locale-aware, you could do it like this with `sh`, `date`, `grep` and `coreutils`:

```
days="($(  for i in $(seq  7); do date -d 2013/01/$i +%a; done | paste -sd'|'))" 
months="($(for i in $(seq 12); do date -d 2013/$i/01 +%b; done | paste -sd'|'))"
```

You can now grep the date format like this:

```
grep -E "${days}-${months}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}" infile
```

Note that you seem to be using a non-standard Wednesday abbreviation, if this is not a locale variation, you need to modify the `days` line to this:

```
days="($(for i in $(seq  7); do date -d 2013/01/$i +%a; done | sed s/Wed/Wen/ | paste -sd'|'))"
```